# Proving surjectivity of a function

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$Y\setminus f(A) \subseteq f(X\setminus A) \leftrightarrow f= \mbox{surjective}$$
$$\forall A\subseteq X$$
I need some help proving this.

Comment: I know that I should assume function's surjectivity and then proove that the first part exists and then vice versa. I edited the first post, I had made an error.

Comment: Yes, Yes.. It is alright...which way do you feel it is easy?? Suppose $f$ is surjective... Then??? what would be $Y$???

Comment: I would take 2 different elements from each set $y\in f(X/A)$ and $x\in X/A$ next I should show with their relation that f is surjective while second part is subset of the first one.

Comment: By the way, it's not correct to write "$f = \text{surjective}$" for "$f$ is surjective."  Although "is" sometimes denotes equality in English, this is not one of those times.  If $f = \text{surjective}$ and $g = \text{surjective}$ then $f=g$, regardless of what "surjective" means.  But of course not all surjective functions are equal.

Answer (score 1):

If $Y\setminus f(A) \subset f(X\setminus A)$ for all $A\subset X$ : We want to show that $f$ is surjective, so take $A = X$, then
$$
Y\setminus f(X) \subset f(\emptyset) = \emptyset \Rightarrow f(X) = Y
$$
and hence $f$ is surjective.

If $f$ is surjective, then for any $A \subset X$, we want to show that $Y\setminus f(A) \subset f(X\setminus A)$ : Suppose $y \in Y\setminus f(A)$, we want to prove that $y \in f(X\setminus A)$. There is an $x\in X$ such that $f(x) = y$; then $y \notin f(A)$ implies that $x\notin A$. Hence,
$$
x\in X\setminus A \Rightarrow y \in f(X\setminus A)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f$ is surjective, i.e.,  $f(X)=Y$

we have to prove for any $A\subseteq X$,

$Y-f(A)\subseteq f(X-A)$ i.e., $f(X)-f(A)\subseteq f(X-A)$ 
(Is this hint sufficient ?)

Conversely, it is given that : for all $A\subseteq X$, you have :

$$Y-f(A)\subseteq f(X-A)$$

what does this give if you take $A=\emptyset$?

$Y-f(\emptyset)\subseteq f(X-\emptyset)$.. What does this mean ?

> $Y\subseteq f(X)$... and you know $f(X)\subseteq Y$.. So ?

Comment: Please use the question mark more sparingly. We get its meaning also when you use just one at a time.

Comment: @Lord_Farin : Ok :)